# how to store the Kannada in SQL Server 2005

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

I want to store Kannada in sql server 2005. I tried to insert via query and baraha direct. that stored as ?????

. Can any one please tell me how i can store Kannada in sql server 2005.
i went through the following link they are telling Kannada is not supporting by default. Is it true?.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143508%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

or am i need to set any collation?

Comment: nope thats not true you can save **KANNADA** letters in sql server you need to mention unicodedata nvarcharchar(max)

Comment: how to do that? how to change that to Unicode? during the installation only?... or afterwords also possible?

Comment: i'm not sure if it works in sql-s 2005 but it works in sql 2012 you can see [demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/46f0f/1) i put

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
    CREATE TABLE dbo.nammakannada
    ( language NVARCHAR(50)
    , unicodeDa NVARCHAR(200)
    )

    INSERT INTO dbo.nammakannada (language, unicodeDa)
    VALUES
     ('English', N'my example')
    , ('Kannada', N'ಈ ಕನ್ನಡ ಬ್ಲಾಗ್ .')

    SELECT * FROM dbo.nammakannada;
    GO
```

**[fiddle_demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/46f0f/1)**

Comment: I accepted your answer. but i want to know about the size. I mean to store 1 Kannada character(ಈ) how much size is needed?

Comment: i have no idea on that,but you need to save entire text <kannada string> then use **NVARCHAR(MAX)**,its safe to use && no data truncation  in some most case :)

Answer (score 1):

Create the Table column Data type as "NVarchar" into which you need to insert data.
 If column data type is NVARCHAR then you can insert any Unicode value and it will be stored successfully, but if your column data type was different while inserting data the those unicode values will be stored as '??????'.